# Laravel Livewire with Select2: Losing State on Dynamic Input Addition and Language Change

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am working on a Laravel project using Livewire with Select2 for a dynamic form. I have encountered a challenge where Select2 loses its enhanced functionality when I dynamically add new select inputs or change the language, which alters the options in the select inputs. My objective is to preserve the Select2 state across these dynamic updates.

**Issue Description:**

When I add a new select input dynamically (addInput method), or when I change the language (which should filter the options in Select2 based on the language), the existing Select2 inputs lose their enhanced state and revert to standard HTML select elements.
This issue occurs despite using wire:ignore.self to prevent Livewire from updating the Select2 component itself.

**Code Sample:**

*Livewire Component: (CreateRecipe.php)*

```
// Livewire component methods like addInput, updatedLanguage, etc.
// Relevant properties: $inputs, $language
```

*Blade Template: (create-recipe.blade.php)*

```
{{-- Language Selection --}}
<div>
    <x-input.select wire:model.live="language" id="language_id">
        <option value="">Select Language</option>
        @foreach ($languages as $lang)
            <option value="{{$lang}}">{{$lang}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </x-input.select>
</div>

{{-- Dynamic Inputs for Ingredients --}}
@foreach($inputs as $key => $input)
    <div wire:ignore.self class="w-1/4">
        <select data-type="ingredient" wire:key="ingredients-for-language-{{$language}}" wire:model.live="inputs.{{ $key }}.ingredient"
                id="input_{{ $key }}_ingredient" class="form-select block w-full">
            <option value="">Select Ingredient</option>
            @foreach ($ingredients as $ingredient)
                <option value="{{$ingredient->id}}">{{$ingredient->name}} - ({{$ingredient->language}})</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**JavaScript for Select2:**

```
function initSelect2() {
    $('select[id^="input_"][id$="_ingredient"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('select2-hidden-accessible')) {
            $(this).select2('destroy');
        }
        $(this).select2({
            placeholder: 'Select Ingredient',
            allowClear: true,
        });
    });
}
// Initialization and Livewire hooks
$(document).ready(initSelect2);
Livewire.hook('commit', initSelect2);
Livewire.on('ingredientCreated', initSelect2);
```

**Attempts to Resolve:**

- I've tried reinitializing Select2 on Livewire's commit hook and after
  dynamically adding new inputs or changing language.
- I have used wire:ignore.self to prevent Livewire from fully
  re-rendering the Select2 component, but the issue persists.
- I've also experimented with different Livewire hooks and JavaScript
  timing strategies

**Questions:**

1. How can I maintain the Select2 state and functionality when
   dynamically adding new inputs or changing the language in a Livewire
   component?
2. Is there a more effective way to integrate Livewire with Select2 for
   dynamic forms?

**Environment:**

Laravel Version: 10.0

Livewire Version: 3.2

Select2 Version: 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I will answer a part of your question:
dynamic inputs are not allowed in livewire, by experience, I had the same issue when I add livewire models dynamically, the result is that they are not working.

#### how i resolved it:

I put hidden livewire input with the same models.name, the reason is that this library loads the nessary js code at the beginning, then if a new model appears, unfortunately, its corresponding js code is not loaded though.